# SharePoint 2010 - site page/home.aspx is missing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating SharePoint 2010 site collection and facing one problem, when i create a site collection its successfully created but when i browse the site its showing error page.

I enters the URL like **http://computername:81** and hit enter button, it automatically change to URL **http://computername:81/SitePages/Home.aspx** and display error page.

When i change URL to **http://computername:81/Default.aspx** its running fine.

I noticed that there is missing Home.aspx page in **site pages** directory.

I also check **Wiki Page Home Page** feature is enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards:

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do ?

I mean do you want to make Home.aspx available thaen you have to create it again.

If not then Change the welcome page for your site from Home.aspx to  default.aspx

go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Under Look and Feel  Click on Welcome Page.

Change it From Home.aspx to default.aspx

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: First of all thank your for you comments.

Actually few days ago, i was brand my SharePoint site and it was running fine. I has added some web parts before this error on Home.aspx.

After few days, it seems such errors and i just want to recover it back and run /site page/Home.aspx.

Comment: Ok you mean to say after adding some web parts this error starts coming ? If yes then try to make sure due to which web part it starts giving error. Append ?Contents=1 to your Home.aspx and may be it will go into maintenance view of the page. Close one by one webparts and see if you can find the problematic web part.

Comment: This not due to addition of any web part. Infect if i create new web application and under create new site collection, when i try to browse it show same error.

Eeven if i want to edit web site newly created in SharePoint designer. It asks for credential, i enter user name and password, after some processing SharePont Designer shows error "Ther server could not complete your request."

Comment: In web application i can browse lists pages but can not browse any document library page from View All Contents.

Comment: This is log created by this error

0x0EEC SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     nasq Medium   Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://dredge-pc:83/SitePages/Home.aspx))  
01/18/2013 16:56:47.91  w3wp.exe (0x070C)                        0x0EEC SharePoint Foundation          Logging Correlation Data       xmnv

Comment: Medium   Name=Request (GET:http://dredge-pc:83/SitePages/Home.aspx) 46e00821-6380-4247-b9ef-6bea36f17f1e
01/18/2013 16:56:47.92  w3wp.exe (0x070C)                        0x0EEC SharePoint Foundation          Logging Correlation Data       xmnv Medium   Site=/ 46e00821-6380-4247-b9ef-6bea36f17f1e
01/18/2013 16:56:47.92  w3wp.exe (0x070C)                        0x0EEC SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     b4ly

Comment: High     Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=8.97457119283266 46e00821-6380-4247-b9ef-6bea36f17f1e
01/18/2013 16:56:47.97  w3wp.exe (0x070C)                        0x0EEC SharePoint Server              General                        0000